# Book about a spacecraft flying towards a distant planet that had been seeded hundreds of years earlier

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book I started to read more than 20 years ago.  It starts out with a ship flying towards a planet that had been seeded hundreds of years earlier.  It has a lot of political intrigue and the people sort of look down on the people on the planet because they really are not all that human anyway.  That is all I can remember.  I would love to finish reading that book someday.

Comment: Welcome Daniel, please take our [tour] and refer to our [help] for guidance. Enjoy Sci-fi & Fantasy.

Comment: Seeded with what? Bacteria, algae, grass? The planet people, are they humanoid aliens or mutated colonists from earth? Does the ship reach the planet, or don't you know because you didn't get that far? Why is the ship flying to the planet? Is its mission scientific, commercial, military?

Comment: [The Songs of Distant Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Songs_of_Distant_Earth)?

Comment: [*The Great Explosion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Explosion)? [*The Forgotten Planet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forgotten_Planet)?